# Render Arbitrary HTML in custom summary_field

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm trying to render HTML in a Gridfield using a custom Summary Field in SS3.3 the [older technique](http://www.silverstripe.org/community/forums/general-questions/show/30849) no longer works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried casting like this?

```
$config->getComponentByType('GridFieldDataColumns')
    ->setFieldCasting(array('MyField' => 'HTMLText->forTemplate'));
```

Comment: Whats the solution with SS4?